# Play for Scala: Mock singleton in ScalaTest

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, scalatest

I have the following Play Controller class that I need to test with ScalaTest:

```
class RunFormula @Inject() (dbCache: DbCache) extends Controller  {
    // some code
}
```

The class `DbCache` is a singleton:

```
@Singleton
class DbCache @Inject() (properties: Properties) {
    // some getters and setters
}
```

And this is the test class:

```
class RunFormulaTest extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerSuite with MockitoSugar {

    implicit override lazy val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder().build

    @Inject val dbCache : DbCache = null

    val controller = new RunFormula(dbCache)

    // more test code

}
```

When I run the test, the object `dbCache` inside `RunFormula` is null, my understanding was that Guice would create the instance when it's injected but apparently it's not.

Note that the controller `RunFormula` works correctly with `dbCache` injected in the non-test scenario.

How to fix the test?

Comment: ScalaTest doesn't use dependency injection to create your suite classes. You have to construct the classes you test manually. Or you can use Guice api so it creates instances for you, but still you have to call it manually. Few notes though: 1) do you need real instance of DbCache? perhaps you'd want to mock it. 2) using OneAppPerSuite adds a lot of overhead, you probably don't need running app for unit tests.

Comment: Yes, I need the real instance of DbCache, not a mockup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of ways to do it.
First of all, if you want to get the instance of your controller with the database correctly injected you should do something like this:

```
val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder().build
val controller = app.injector.instanceOf[RunFormula]
```

This will get you the instance with your database.
You can control the connection of your database in test mode by setting the appropriate properties in your application.conf file.

You can also create an instance of your controller with a database instance you can created by yourself:

```
val dbUrl = sys.env.getOrElse("DATABASE_URL", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/yourdatabase?user=username&password=password")
val database = Databases("org.postgresql.Driver", dbUrl,"testingzzz")
val controller = new RunFormula(database)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking for injecting a database, I need to inject a singleton class (`DbCache` in my example) in the controller..

Comment: This is what I showed in the first code example, if you want the actual instance of your database then use: app.injector.instanceOf[DbCache]

Comment: This did the trick: `val dbCache = app.injector.instanceOf[DbCache]`